# Is there a cloud IDE with Assembla/GitHub integration?

Tags: github, ide, cloud, assembla, chromebook

With the new Chromebook launch I have been wondering, is there a cloud IDE that could be used from Chrome and that has an Assembla and/or GitHub integration for hosting the projects?

I'm thinking about Rails development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cloud9](https://c9.io/) (not exactly free, past one private workspace) has [GitHub and BitBucket integration](https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_github_workspace.html), and is all about collaboration.

And it does supports the ability to [run a Rails app](https://docs.c9.io/running_a_rails_app.html).

Comment: Note: a similar one, to check: CodeEnvy: https://codenvy.com/features.jsp (also as a Chrome plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/codenvy-ide/lefigjbiimiemfhjmibbgemkpenelmag), as Cloud9 is (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cloud9/nbdmccoknlfggadpfkmcpnamfnbkmkcp)

Comment: Cloud9 looks great! I signed up with GitHub, cloned a project, modified the README, committed and pushed in less than 5 minutes. I'm still trying to run a rails app though...

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is possible to integrate with [assembla](http://www.assembla.com/plans?affiliate=acroitor). There are a couple steps to do that:

1. Have an assembla account(paid or free) and space with a git repository.Unfortunatelly Could9 does not support svn repositories. So on assembla side you;ll have something
   like: https://www.assembla.com/code/<your-space>/git/nodes. If it is
   private repository your git url will be
   git@git.assembla.com:<your-space>.git or if it is a public
   repository you will have git://git.assembla.com/<your-space>.git
2. Have a Cloud9 account
3. Go to you could9 dashboard
4. Look for "Show your SSH key" under "Account settings" pannel on the right
5. Copy the ssh key and add it to your account on assembla at: https://www.assembla.com/user/edit/edit_git_settings
6. Now create your Cloud9 workspace with "Clone from url" using assembla git url from step 2.
7. You're done.
8. Do the rest of the ordinary stuff you usually do, clone, commit, push, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Nitrous](https://pro.nitrous.io) has first-class github integration built in. It's very easy to add your Nitrous ssh keys to Github and work seamlessly.

https://community.nitrous.io/docs/connect-to-github

There is also a default Ruby on Rails starter template with a sample project included. Signup is 100% free for the first project:

https://pro.nitrous.io/stacks/ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Cloud development platform Nitrous.io [shut down](https://techcrunch.com/2016/10/31/cloud-development-platform-nitrous-io-shuts-down/) in 2016.

Answer (score 1):

[Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) has an application for simple GitHub usage, and a browser  Terminal with full system root access, so you can use it for Assembla/Github/anything. Basically if you can do it on a Ubuntu machine, you can do it on Koding, so your Assembla/Github issue is easy :)